# Handlebars moves '@partial-block' content to end of page

Tags: html, handlebars.js, webpack-handlebars-loader

I am using handlebars with webpack and handlebars-loader (A handlebars template loader for webpack.) to implement a multi page web app. Below is the structure of my views folder (.hbs files)

- views

  - components

    - sidebar.hbs
  - layouts

    - default.hbs
    - product.hbs
  - index.hbs
  - product-1.hbs
  - product-2.hbs
  - ...

My problem is that I see a weird behavior from 'partial-block' in handlebars. I have two layouts that wrap the main content of each page. but my layout doesn't load the 'partial-block' in the right  line. wherever I use partial-block in the layout, handlebars will close the body and html tag at that place and will render the partial-block content after html closing tag.

below is my sample default layout that loads partial-block inside body :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>{{meta.title}}</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
</head>

<body class="theme-light">

    {{#if @partial-block}}
    {{> @partial-block }}
    {{/if}}
</body>

</html>
```

My index.hbs file that uses default layout

```
{{> layouts/default }}
<main id="index" class="index">
    <p>This is index content</p>
</main>

{{layouts/default}}
```

And rendered html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>My Test Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
</head>

<body class="theme-light">

</body>

</html>
<main id="index" class="index">
    <p>This is index content</p>
</main>
```

Like I said, the main tag goes after closing html tag which is not expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

there is a wrong syntax.

you should type like this.

```html
{{#> layouts/default }}
  <main id="index" class="index">
    <p>This is index content</p>
  </main>
{{/layouts/default}}
```